# Passing data to envers revision listener

Tags: java, playframework, hibernate-envers

I'm trying to store revision comments using Enver's RevisionEntity so that it's in the same table as the revision ID and timestamp and is stored only once even if multiple entities are changed.

My current approach is

- controller action that handles the request puts comments into a session variable
- my custom RevisionListener reads the session variable, adds the comments to the RevisionEntity, and clears the session variable

I'm not that happy with this approach though. It seems like it will be prone to race conditions and other goofy behavior. Is there any way I can make this more solid? Maybe by accessing the RevisionEntity directly in the controller action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I really understand your problem, but if you only want to store some information during the request-handling, you can use
`Http.Request.current().args`. As the [description in the API docs](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/1.2.2/play/mvc/Http.Request.html#args)  says, it's:

> Free space to store your request specific data

Your controller action will just need to copy the comments from `params` (or wherever else they're coming from) and store them in the `args` map, and then the RevisionListener can retrieve them from there.

Comment: I was thrown off by the listener being off in space where I can't manipulate it, but passing the data via the request args is working great.

Comment: So how do you access Http.Request.current().args from RevisionListener??